# java JMenuBar not visible? Why?

Tags: java, swing, jmenubar

I cannot figure out why my menu bar isn't visible. I have following code:

//Main

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
public class Menu extends JFrame{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500,350);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        menuBar mbObj = new menuBar();

        mbObj.menuBar(frame);
    }
}
```

//Menu Bar class

```
public class menuBar{

        private JMenu file,edit;
        private JMenuItem nFile ,oFile,sFile,saFile,exit;
        private JMenuItem undo,copy,paste;
        private JMenuBar bar;

        public void menuBar(JFrame frame){
            bar = new JMenuBar();
            frame.setJMenuBar(bar);
            bar.setVisible(true);
            file = new JMenu("File");
            edit = new JMenu("Edit");
            bar.add(file);
            bar.add(edit);
        }    
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `setVisible(true)` on the top-level window, here a JFrame, only **after** adding all components, including the `JMenuBar`. You will also want to avoid calling `setSize(...)` on anything, and instead use layout managers and call `pack()` on the JFrame after adding all components and before calling `setVisible(true)`.

So the order should be:

```
// create JFrame
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Foo");

// here add all components to the JFrame
// .....
// done adding components

frame.pack();
// frame.setLocationRelativeToPlatform(true); // if you wish
frame.setVisible(true);
```

As an aside class names should begin with an upper case letter, and dont have methods with the exact same name as the class, as that creates a "pseudo"-constructor and will confuse everyone.

Comment: **Thenks for all tha informations. Now all is working properly**